# How do I declare global variables in Javascript and change global variables and call global variables?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

First, I declare global variables.
Second, I change the variable's value in a function.
Finally, I call the variable.

```
var a=0;
function a(){
    a=1;
}
console.log(a);
```

I looked forward to the result of 1.
However, I got the result of 0.

How can I change the value of a global variable within a function?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: You never did call the function that would have changed the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to this

```js
var a;
function a(){
    a=1;
}
a = 0;
console.log(a);
```

So the last expression is assigning `0` to the `a`.

If you just mistyped the names, you need to give to the function another name, because `function` overrides the variable - they have the same name. And also call your function before `console.log`.

```js
var a = 0;

function functionA(){
    a = 1;
}

functionA();
console.log(a);
```